# Why does the google javascript client library functions execute last within the angularjs framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api-client

I think it may be my misunderstanding on how the google javascript client libraries are loaded, but why would a javascript api call take least precedence when being invoked within the angularJS framework. I know that sounds a big convoluted so here is a specific example.

This is a full web app so I'll just narrow down what I think is the most relevant code. This is the function I am calling in my Controller.:

```
$scope.isRegistered = function () {
var joe = function () {

    gapi.client.conference.isRegistered().
        execute(function(resp){
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                if (resp.error){
                    $log.error('There was an Error');
                }
                else {
                    $log.info("Success");
                    return resp.data;
                }
            });
        });
    };

    joe();

    $log.info("testing");
};
```

I have this in my html (partial) as a test case for this to execute:

```
<button ng-click="isRegistered()">IsRegs</button>
```

And when I click on my button. What I expected was the console to print out the gapi.client function first and then the "testing" string afterwards:

1.)"success"
2.)"testing"

It prints the following (sorry not enough rep. points to post a picture):

1.)"testing"
2.)"success

I ran more tests, but the bottom line, is that I was expecting the function, joe(), to execute first before $log.info("testing"). Why does $log.info("testing") execute first, and then the gapi call?

I will be needing to execute the gapi calls in a particular order and it is taking least precedence all the time, based on my tests. It will always execute and finish the rest of the function body before ever actually executing the gapi call.

Why is this?

I'd want to execute the gapi call first in the order that I write the code, NOT last. Long story short, this messes-up the logic with the rest of my code if it is not invoked in the order that I write it.

Any hints as to why this is? Can I override the gapi invocation for it to execute with first priority?

I'm still perusing the [google client javascript library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/dev/dev_jscript) for more clues. Any help here would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: it looks to me like this is an async function;  you have "queued" the callback, the code then continues, and when the async operation has finished, the callback is performed.  Therefore, your last `$log` statement is reached before the callback is.  This is how async works; otherwise, you'd be waiting for the server response, which might take seconds or minutes, and the client would be completely unresponsive.

Comment: basically, this has nothing to do with "precedence", and despite what you suggest here, you don't want the code to execute line by line exactly the way you wrote it, waiting for each line to finish; rather, you want to adapt your other code to the async nature of using remote APIs.

Comment: Brunt's solution below touches on what you were talking about in regards to an async call. I wasn't sure of the right term to look-up, in this case being, async. I noticed as well, that it did "queue" the callback. Long story short, I tried running do-while loops when previously diagnosing the problem. 

So say for example, my do-while loop ran a total of 20 times, the gapi call would be "queued" up to 20 times in what I would assume would be some sort of "stack." "testing" would be printed 20 times before 20 success.

Comment: For a button click, this avoids that problem as it only executes once, however, the gapi call to, isRegistered, doesn't take that long to "finish." 

Why, in a loop, would it print all the $logs first, then, the gapi? "testing" should print sometime between 1-20 of the loop if the async call needs to finish, well, asynchronously. 

I guess this should be another Stack Overflow question.

Comment: If you do happen to know the answer to the follow-up, let me know and I can post another question and pass you along the upvote credits. 

Just let me know. 

Thanks for the comment on ayncs, as it helps clear up what I should research further for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "testing" string is always printed first due to the asynchronous nature of the Google API request (you get the response after the execution of the `$log.info("testing");` line). One way of getting the result you want is to use the `$q` service:

```
// need to inject the $q service
$scope.isRegistered = function () {
  var joe = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    gapi
      .client
      .conference
      .isRegistered()
      .execute(function (res) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
          if (res.error) {
            $log.error('There was an Error');
            deferred.reject(res.error);
          }
          else {
            $log.info("Success");
            deferred.resolve(res.data);
          }
        });
      });
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  joe()
    .then(function (data) {
      $log.info("Got some data", data);
      $log.info("testing");
    });
};
```

Comment: Awesome, I just tried out your solution and it worked.  I think I have to read-up a bit more on the async calls as well as this $q and defer functions/services from angular.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but it won't show since I don't have enough points. Just want to make sure you get credited. I'm assuming SO accounts for this.

Comment: Ok good, cause it doesn't show since I don't have enough rep points. Wasn't sure.

And curious, where did you learn about angular? Are you self-taught or did you go to school for it? I just ask cause I'm mostly self-taught and just going through the angular docs and material online. Wondering if there is a "better" way to learn.

If you have any recommendations of material or courses, I'd love to know.

Anyways, thanks again for the quick fix. I'll investigate more "deeply" those function calls used in your answer.

Comment: I learned Angular mostly by myself thanks to egghead.io, the official doc and some videos on Youtube. I also use it at work so I learned things thanks to colleagues too. I recommend visiting the following Github project: [AngularJS learning](https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS-Learning). I also recommend the README of the Q project to learn how to use promises: [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) ;)

Comment: Awesome man. Thanks for the recommendations! If I could throw more S.O. points I would lol.

Comment: Wow. I checked out that egghead.io and there is tons of information. This is great.

Don't know if it helps, but I have been using Lynda.com, Skillshare, and the Angular docs for most of my web dev. learning. There are some cool videos on Lynda (though not as much information on Angular) but a good amount of tutorials with everything neatly organized. Granted it is a paid subscription (it is part of my uni tuition) but I think I'd be purchasing a subscript once I graduate given how helpful it has been to me.

It gives you a good overview of new tech in a seamless efficient way. Hope it helps.